# import firebase error in only one class

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3

#### Question

Why does one class show an error when `import`ing `Firebase`, and the others don't?

#### Details

- I have about a dozen classes, one of which shows the error
- I've had the project working for months, and I've not had the error until today
- Xcode 8.3.1
- When I build the app it says 'build succeeded', yet this error is still shown.
- I can still run the app, even with this error showing. However, when this view is loaded, the app crashes

Screenshots showing the errors

[image]

[image]

Pod file entries

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

App file structure - the two classes in the screen shots are those in the expanded folders

[image]

I have re-installed the pod file, and cleaned and rebuilt the xcode project a few times, but the error remains.

If there's any other information needed let me know.

Comment: Can you post the file structure? Perhaps the swift file that has the error is outside the scope of the imported framework.

Comment: @MarkDodds - done - both classes are in the same location

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the error was because I created Firebase reference variables, but didn't initialise them

So I had it set up like

```
class SessionDetailsController: DatasourceController {

    var firRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func foo(){
        firRef.child(users).child(contacts).observe() { }
    }
}
```

where I had forgotten to initialise the `firRef` object in `viewDidLoad()`

```
class SessionDetailsController: DatasourceController {

    var firRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    func foo(){
        firRef.child(users).child(contacts).observe() { }
    }
}
```

After correctly initialising them the error has gone.